# Can I hide some fields in YouTrack by issue type?

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I want to customize issues at the YouTrack.

For example:
We have custom fields `field1` and `fields2`. When issue type is `Epic` I need to show `field1` and when issue type is `Bug` - `field2`

How to write workflow in this case?

---

Information about software:
YouTrack 6.0 Build 12634 [04-Mar-2015 18:21]
YouTrack Workflow Editor 40.3384

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is clear, but it's not possible. Here's the respective request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-10612.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is really old but you can now do this out of the box in version 2018.1

https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/whatsnew/

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question to the JetBrains support recently. For now, the recommended approach is to have one project per issue type. I use this technique and it actually works very well. We created 4 projects: "Project A bugs", "Project A features", "Project B bugs" and "Project B features".

You can then create easily a "Project A" filter, using the query "{Project A bugs} or {Project A features}", if you want to concentrate on Project A only.